# Removing Oracle Java Programs from Applications menu

Tags: slingshot

I installed Oracle Java on my system. All I wanted was access to the java and javac commands for the command line. However, I noticed that in the application menu four new programs showed up: "Oracle Java 8 Console," "Oracle Java 8 Mission Control," "Oracle Java 8 VisualVM," "Oracle Java 8 Web Start." How do I remove these applications from the applications menu, or better yet, how would I remove them from my system altogether (if that would be possible without hurting my ability to compile and run java programs)?

Answer (score 1):

Fast: Click right in file icon and run "New windows as Administrator" put the password and go to:

```
/usr/share/applications/
```

find the java icons that you want to remove and done